# lambda expression ClassCastException in Java

Tags: java, java-8, casting, java-stream

I am trying to learn streaming in java 8. Following is my code :

**Main.java**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Person person = new Person("FirstName", "LastName");
        List<Person> personList = new ArrayList<>();
        personList.add(person);

        Place place = new Place("name", "country");
        List<Place> placeList = new ArrayList<>();
        placeList.add(place);


        List<List<Object>> objects = new ArrayList<>();
        objects.add(Collections.singletonList(personList));
        objects.add(Collections.singletonList(placeList));

        List<Object> persons = objects.get(0);
        List<String> firstNames = persons.stream()
                .map(o -> ((Person)o).getFirstName())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        firstNames.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

**Person.java**

```
@Data
public class Person {
    String firstName;
    String lastName;

    public Person(String firstName, String lastName) {
        setFirstName(firstName);
        setLastName(lastName);
    }
}
```

**Place.java**

```
@Data
public class Place {
    String name;
    String country;

    public Place(String name, String country) {
        setName(name);
        setCountry(country);
    }
}
```

**Exception :**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to Person
    at Main.lambda$main$0(Main.java:28)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.Collections$2.tryAdvance(Collections.java:4717)
    at java.util.Collections$2.forEachRemaining(Collections.java:4725)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)
    at Main.main(Main.java:29)
```

I have `List` of `List` which is holding `Object` (I am using `Object` since I want to use a different type of object to be stored into the collection). I am storing the collection of `Person` and collection of `Place` into this `List` of `List` collection.

Inside the streaming, I am trying to get the only `firstName` of all the persons. However, when I use lamba expression which goes through each element and get the firstName does not work with casting.

**Question:**

1. Am I doing anything wrong?
2. Is there any other way(other than `map` in streaming) to get all the FirstName of the Person Object with stream API?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`personList` is a List of Person

`Collections.singletonList(personList)` is a List of List of Person

`objects` is a List of List of List of Person/Place.

```
    List<Object> persons = objects.get(0);   // persons is a List of List of Person
    List<String> firstNames = persons.stream()  
    //each element in the stream is a List of Person, so you cannot cast it to Person.
            .map(o -> ((Person)o).getFirstName())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You can either remove the singletonList function so that you reduce a level of list:

```
    List<List<?>> objects = new ArrayList<>();
    objects.add(personList);
    objects.add(placeList);
```

or go deeper one list when you do map:

```
    List<String> firstNames = persons.stream() 
            //Because persons is declared as List of Objects, so you need to cast each element into a List before calling get 
            .map(o -> ((Person)((List)o).get(0))).getFirstName())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: To remove `singletonList`, you have to change the declaration to `List<List<?>> objects`, as `personList` and `placeList` do not have the type `List<Object>`.

Comment: @Holger Not necessarily. Object is a root class for everything and any object can be declared as Object. like `Object o = new ArrayList()"

Comment: That doesn’t matter. You can’t assign a `List<Person>` to a variable of type `List<Object>` and hence, you can’t store a `List<Person>` into a `List<List<Object>>`.

Comment: @Holger I see what you mean. Yes you are right. Updated answer